# How can I use git in daemonized python code?

Tags: python, git, python-daemon

My project I am writing is a daemon, which i can run undaemonized for debugging purposes.

I am trying to use simple git functionality in Python.
Here is my git Class.

```
import os
import subprocess


class Git():

    def __init__(self, server_log, config, repo_path):

        self.log = server_log
        self.config = config

        self.repo_path = repo_path
        self.repo_name = os.path.basename(repo_path.strip("/"))

        self.base_command = "/usr/bin/git "


    def push(self):

        command = self.base_command + "push"
        output, return_code = self.run_command(command)
        self.print_output("push", output, return_code)


    def pull(self):

        command = self.base_command + "pull"
        output, return_code = self.run_command(command)
        self.print_output("pull", output, return_code)


    def commit(self, message):

        command = self.base_command + "commit -a -m \"" + message +  "\""
        output, return_code = self.run_command(command)
        self.print_output("commit", output, return_code)


    def print_output(self, command_type, output, return_code):

        self.log.info("Git " + command_type + ": " + self.repo_name + " Returncode: " + str(return_code))
        self.log.info("\n" + output)


    def run_command(self, command):

        self.log.info("Command: " + command)
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, cwd = self.repo_path, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
        (stdout_data, stderr_data) = process.communicate()
        return_code = process.returncode

        output = stdout_data.strip()
        if stderr_data:
            if output:
                output += "\n"
            output += stderr_data.strip()

        return (output, return_code)
```

This code works as intended in non daemonized context.
But if you combine it with python-daemon it falls apart.

This is how i daemonize, which worked no problem so far.

```
with daemon.DaemonContext(pidfile = daemon.pidfile.PIDLockFile(self.config["pid_file"])):
            self.run_server()
```

The run_server method was asked for, so i include it here:

```
def run_server(self):

        setproctitle.setproctitle("server")

        # Logging
        log = Logger(self.config["logfile"], "Server", self.config["loglevel"], self.config["log_size"], self.config["kept_rotations"])
        # For quit_handler
        self.log = log

        # Register Signal Handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  self.quit_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, self.quit_handler)

        log.print("Server Version " + version.get_version() + " started.")

        scan_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        # Create and start Scan Manager
        scan_manager = ScanManager(log, self.config, scan_queue)
        scan_manager_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=scan_manager.run_manager, name="scan_manager")
        scan_manager_proc.daemon = False
        scan_manager_proc.start()

        # Create and start REST Interfaces
        rest_api = RestApi(log, self.config, scan_queue)
        rest_api_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=rest_api.run_api, name="rest_api")
        rest_api_proc.daemon = False
        rest_api_proc.start()

        # Create and start NginxProxy
        nginx = NginxProxy(log, self.config)
        nginx_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=nginx.start, name="nginx")
        nginx_proc.daemon = False
        nginx_proc.start()

        # Wait for signal.
        signal.pause()

        # Quit processes
        scan_manager_proc.terminate()
        rest_api_proc.terminate()
        nginx_proc.terminate()
        log.print("Stopped")
```

This is the result non daemonized:

```
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git pull
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO: Git pull: repo Returncode: 0
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO:
Already up-to-date.
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git commit -a -m "SetNodeStatus 04.12.2020 11:54 UTC on ['server']"
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO: Git commit: repo Returncode: 0
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO:
[master df88920] SetNodeStatus 04.12.2020 11:54 UTC on ['server']
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
04.12.2020 11:54:38 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git push
04.12.2020 11:54:39 INFO: Git push: repo Returncode: 0
04.12.2020 11:54:39 INFO:
To git@gitserver:repo.git
   428a77e..df88920  master -> master
```

And here it is daemonized:

```
04.12.2020 11:54:50 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git pull
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO: Git pull: repo Returncode: 1
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO:
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git commit -a -m "SetNodeStatus 04.12.2020 11:54 UTC off ['server']"
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO: Git commit: repo Returncode: 128
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO:
error: unable to create temporary file: file already exists
fatal: Error writing version object.
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO: Command: /usr/bin/git push
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO: Git push: repo Returncode: -13
04.12.2020 11:54:51 INFO:
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also implemented this using GitPython with the same effect.

Why is that and how can I make this work?

Solution:

in `subprocess.Popen`stdin defaults to None.
Defining stdin as a pipe fixed the problem.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, cwd = self.repo_path, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
```

Comment: Tangentially related, I believe daemonization should be handled by a system process manager such as systemd, not within your code...

Comment: Try `command = self.base_command + "/push"` insead of  `command = self.base_command + "push"` and so on with `"pull"`

Comment: Can you share your `self.run_server` method's content as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes i did include it.

Comment: Are you using the version of `daemon` from https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/ ? (the tag suggests that you probably area, but it seems worth asking)

Comment: @torek Yes, not directly downloaded but installed via pip3. I found that i was using 2.2.3 and updated to 2.2.4. But no change in behaviour.

Comment: OK, that software itself looks pretty good. In particular it's careful to make sure that stdin, stdout, and stderr are not closed. (Closing those can cause this sort of problem sometimes because Git expects newly opened file descriptors to be >= 3 numerically.) So at this point I don't have any particular ideas as to what's breaking.

Comment: @torek Thank you, you fixed it. In `subprocess.Popen` stdin defaults to None. Based on your information i defined stdin as a Pipe, which made the difference.

Comment: Interesting, because with stdin=None it should leave descriptor zero alone. But, OK, it works now :-)